How to debug 'Ion execution failed' error in Datomic Ion HTTP endpoint?
I'm setting up a Datomic Ions system and encountering an error when trying to access the HTTP direct endpoint. Here's my current setup:

Successfully established client and connection
Completed push and deploy operations
Attempting to access the HTTP endpoint using the IonApiGatewayEndpoint value
Receiving error: "Ion execution failed"

Additionally, I have two AWS alarms active:

ConsumedWriteCapacityUnits < 150 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes
ConsumedReadCapacityUnits < 600 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes

As someone new to AWS, I'm not sure where to look for relevant logs to debug this issue.
Questions:

Where can I find the relevant logs to debug this error?
Do these capacity-related alarms indicate a potential cause of the failure?

Any guidance on debugging steps or common issues would be appreciated.
